# Can an exception be used by more than one trigger? Is there a general exception that can be used by any trigger?

Tags: exception, triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

About 18 months ago, I created an exception for a trigger which works fine. Now, when I have tried to create a new exception for a new trigger, it looks more like an error. So the trigger still compiles and the exception still halts the trigger, but it does not look professional. It says:

[image]

I would expect just:

[image]

But with the message "Supplier Required in Line Source Tab."

I guess my question wasn't clear enough and for this I apologise. With lots of exceptions which do nothing else than to inform the user there is an issue and what it is, then why not just create one exception and change the message each time? I believe that somehow an exception belongs to a particular trigger. If that is the case, how is this done?

Comment: what about internationalisation? changing the exception description to the language of current application user? consider this general idea. In general, things such as giving descriptions, opening help pages and such a left for the client application, it is part of "user interface/experience" layer. And `USRDEF_NOSUPPLIERINALS` is to be considered just an ID, a kind of named constant. Your application is expected to handle "SQL exception" kind of errors, find those IDs, match them against some error descriptions database and then generate human-readable text on the client side.

Comment: Your title asks a totally different question than you're asking in your question body. As to the question of the title: yes, a single exception can be used by any PSQL code in the same database. As to the problem in the body of the question: this seems to be an application specific problem with how it renders exceptions, so if you want them to be shown differently, change how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

How your application display errors is not directly related to how these errors are raised. ISC API Guide describe how to parse status vector and recognize gdscodes so you can extract exception message and show it ignoring the rest.